# How to print or access values from this names list?

Tags: c#, class, console

I am trying to create a simple console card game in c#. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access my players names after they've been created.

I'm trying to create an object array that stores each player in a different index. As the game develops, I will add more properties to the player class (like cards remaining).

I'm hoping to be able to display a players name, id number, etc. but am not sure how to print that value. I've tried `Console.WriteLine(playerList[i])`, but that just prints the the namespace and class. I'm also not able to do anything like `Console.writeLine(playerList[i].name)`, but that doesn't work either.

Any help or feedback is great! Thanks!

```
class Player
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, enter how many players are playing");
        int numOfPlayer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Player[] playerList = CreatePlayers(numOfPlayer);

        //What I'm trying to do! >>
        //Console.WriteLine(playerList[0].name + "'s turn")
    }

    static Player[] CreatePlayers(int amountOfPlayers)
    {
        Player[] playerList = new object[amountOfPlayers];

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for player " + (i + 1));
            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            Player player = new Player();
            player.id = i;
            player.name = playerName;
            playerList[i] = player;
        }
        return playerList;
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
I've changed the Object array into a player array, and I've updated it in the code above. I seem to be able to access the name now by writing Console.Writeline(playerList[0].name.ToString()). Is this a decent way to do it?

Comment: Don't use `object`.

Comment: As metioned don't use an Array of objects. Use an Array of `Player` instead, then you can easily access the properties of said player. If you want to override the default string that is printed when you call `Console.WriteLine(playerList[i]);`, you could override the `ToString()` Method of your Player class. Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method).

Comment: Thank you both! I changed it to an array of Player and was able to get it to display player one's name using Console.WriteLine(playerList[0].name.ToString()); Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `object` with `Player`.
Casting a class to `object` will not be able to reference the members of the original class.

```
class Player
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, enter how many players are playing");
        int numOfPlayer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Player[] playerList = CreatePlayers(numOfPlayer);

        //What I'm trying to do! >>
        Console.WriteLine(playerList[0].name + "'s turn");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Player[] CreatePlayers(int amountOfPlayers)
    {

        Player[] playerList = new Player[amountOfPlayers];

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for player " + (i + 1));
            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            Player player = new Player();
            player.id = i;
            player.name = playerName;
            playerList[i] = player;
        }
        return playerList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Player
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, enter how many players are playing");
        int numOfPlayer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<Player> playerList = CreatePlayers(numOfPlayer);

        //What I'm trying to do! >>
        Console.WriteLine(playerList.ElementAt(0).name + "'s turn");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

   static List<Player> CreatePlayers(int amountOfPlayers)
    {

        List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for player " + (i + 1));
            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            Player player = new Player();
            player.id = i;
            player.name = playerName;
            playerList.Add(player);
        }
        return playerList;
    }
}
```

It is better to use collections for linq or any other advantages of generic collections.